# Get left and top position of highcharts scrollbar

Tags: angularjs, charts, highcharts, highcharts-ng

I wanted to put custom label on highcharts which should be placed on left 
 side of scrollbar. How can I get top and left position of scrollbar.?

I have put label with following code

```
chart.renderer.text('<span style="font-weight:600;"> 1-21 </span>', 20, 120)
        .css({
            color: 'green',
            fontSize: '12px'
        })
        .add();
```

Comment: The left side of which scrollbar? The one that is in the body?

Comment: Yes. If we have more no of records to be shown on x or yAxis then we can specify max and min values based on which highcharts provides a scrollbar on xAxis or yAxis attributes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get position of the scrollbar using `chart.xAxis[0].scrollbar.group.translateX` and `chart.xAxis[0].scrollbar.group.translateY`, for example: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/KeBxNj?editors=1010

Snippet:

```
var chart = Highcharts.chart('container', {
  chart: {
    type: 'bar',
    marginLeft: 150,
    events: {
      load: function () {
        var scrollbar = this.xAxis[0].scrollbar,
            bbox;
        // Render:
        this.customLabel = this.renderer.text('<span style="font-weight:600;"> 1-21 </span>', 0, 0).attr({
          zIndex: 5
        }).add();
        // Get bbox
        bbox = this.customLabel.getBBox();

        // Position label
        this.customLabel.attr({
          x: scrollbar.group.translateX - bbox.width,
          y: scrollbar.group.translateY + bbox.height
        });
      }
    }
  },
  ...
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can determine the scrollbar's left position using the `chart.plotWidth + chart.plotLeft - 25`. Also, the top position can be got using `chart.plotTop + 10`. 
The numeric values are just top and left paddings.

Please have a look at this codepen.
https://codepen.io/samuellawrentz/pen/eKjdpN?editors=1010

Hope this helps :)

Comment: This wont help in case of xAxis scrollbar and there are lot of legends at bottom and we don't know exact no. of legends. It will be totally depend on the data retrieved from db.