# How to allow scrolling both vertically and horizontally in Highcharts?

Tags: javascript, html, angular, highcharts

I am trying to make a chart which has dynamic number of items in both X and Y axes using Highcharts (`highcharts-angular` as wrapper) in Angular app.

I would like to make it scrollable both horizontally and vertically using the browsers `scrollablePlotArea` (which provides native scrolling feature).

I tried setting the required options as mentioned in [Highcharts documentation](https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/chart.scrollablePlotArea), and passed them to the chart. But the chart doesn't show two scrollbars at once.

Below is a piece of sample code, I was working with:

```
chartOptions = {
  chart: {
    width: 400,
    height: 400,
    scrollablePlotArea: {
      minHeight: 800, 
      minWidth: 800
    }
  }
}
```

But only the horizontal scrollbar shows up in this case. If I remove the `minWidth` property, then the vertical height shows up. I do know that *Highstock* does has support for scrolling, but I would like this to be implemented with Highcharts using the native scroll.

Help me resolve this issue.

**EDIT**:
Adding [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/aksn1t6f/) for reference

Comment: Is it because your chart size is smaller than the scrollable min size?

Comment: @MaihanNijat No, for some unknown reason, only one of the scrollbar shows up. I added a fiddle for reference.

Comment: Appears to be a known limitation of current implementation: https://github.com/highcharts/highcharts/blob/792e972d8bbed29b9d9e400e74aa68f8494f2646/js/parts/ScrollablePlotArea.js#L109

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
chartOptions = {
  chart: {
    width: 400,
    height: 400
},
    xAxis: {

        scrollbar: {
            enabled: true
        }

    },
    yAxis: {
          scrollbar: {
            enabled: true
        }

    }

}
```

Comment: this only works for Highstock, and is not part of the Highcharts documentation. However, I tried this one too, but didn't work.

Comment: @starlight https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50982955/get-left-and-top-position-of-highcharts-scrollbar and this  is usefull?